# Arduino Yun logging using external power supply

Tags: logging, arduino

How do I make make my Arduino Yun log without using a PC with serial monitor? Ideally I want it to log data as soon as I plug in my SD card, or as soon as I power my arduino. I'm supplying my arduino with a 9V battery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Other than just doing it?

Comment: As it is now my arduino will only log when I use the micro usb connecting my pc and using the aduino software. Not using the usb, but an external supply like as I want it doesn't seem to log the data.

Comment: Are you using the VIN pin on the GPIO, or are using connecting the 9V battery to a USB cable and using the onboard USB port for power?

Comment: Be carefull Arduino Yun runs on 5v